# NPM (node.js Package manager) can't install tiddlywiki

Tags: node.js, npm, synology, tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

first post at the forum, hopefully with enough details for you to give me a hand ;-)

I'm trying to get "tiddlywiki" (a note taking JavaSkript Application) running on my Synology DS 220 via node.js
used following official tutorial: https://tiddlywiki.com/static/Installing%2520TiddlyWiki%2520on%2520Node.js.html

`npm install -g tiddlywiki`

and also

`sudo npm install -g tiddlywiki`

so far I'm getting only ERR (via SSH and admin):

`rollbackFail... etc ERR ... EAI_AGAIN...`

log containes following:

- 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
- 1 verbose cli [
- 1 verbose cli '/volume1/@appstore/Node.js_v12/usr/local/bin/node',
- 1 verbose cli '/usr/local/bin/npm',
- 1 verbose cli 'install',
- 1 verbose cli '-g',
- 1 verbose cli 'tiddlywiki'
- 1 verbose cli ]
- 2 info using npm@6.14.4
- 3 info using node@v12.16.3
- 4 verbose npm-session a6d7122c26647a30
- 5 silly install loadCurrentTree
- 6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
- 7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for tiddlywiki@latest request to https://registry.npmjs.org/tiddlywiki failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org
- 8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
- 9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 20092ms
- 10 verbose type system
- 11 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/tiddlywiki failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org
- 11 verbose stack at ClientRequest. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
- 11 verbose stack at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:310:20)
- 11 verbose stack at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
- 11 verbose stack at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
- 11 verbose stack at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
- 11 verbose stack at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
- 11 verbose stack at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
- 12 verbose cwd /volume1/homes/admin_DSstandard4568
- 13 verbose Linux 4.4.59+
- 14 verbose argv "/volume1/@appstore/Node.js_v12/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "tiddlywiki"
- 15 verbose node v12.16.3
- 16 verbose npm v6.14.4
- 17 error code EAI_AGAIN
- 18 error errno EAI_AGAIN
- 19 error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/tiddlywiki failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org
- 20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

what i also was trying:

`npm install` (for update, no reaction/new version...)

`npm config rm proxy npm config rm https-proxy`

> then this
> `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/ >also npm config set strict-ssl false`

...so everything I could find here or on the internet

my setup:

- I use the onboard encryption for the home-folder ...obviously starting the install process only when folder is decrypted
- Log In via ssh and admin (no problem there / can switch between folders etc, but I use different port for security)
- node v12 used (v8 would also be available) ...also tried to run a HelloWorld.js via SSH from home ...working
- using a FritzBox-Router with the standard security settings (so far no ports freed for the DS, but DS has standard internet access ...also checked via Package Manager on the DSM, finds packages and also installing there works =way I installed nodev12)

Hopefully someone knows whats the issue / it seems npm has no access to the web/repo??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

have found the solution myself:
"sudo ping 1.1.1.1" was already functioning over SSH
"sudo ping registry.npmjs.org" got me "Temporary failure in name resolution"

so for Synology go in DSM: Control Panel / Network / General: and set DNS-server manualy (Google etc)

after this it worked!
...hope it helps somebody else